# How can I avoid the default page 404 of django?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-errors

For example when I'm in http://mydomain.com/myapp/schools/
but if you remove some of the url such as a slash, http://mydomain.com/myapp/schools the error 404 with all the urls that I have in my application and it is wrong for a page, what can I do for this? I have seen that in a django sites page does not change unless it is valid and remains in the current page.

Any idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not really clear but if what you want is that http://mydomain.com/myapp/schools redirects to http://mydomain.com/myapp/schools/ then make sure the `APPEND_SLASH` settings is set to `True`

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#append-slash

Answer (score 2):

By writing a custom 404 handler.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views